# How to implement getting loss with pytorch on NLP?

Tags: nlp, lstm, dimension, loss, cross-entropy

I'm studying about NLP with just simple toy project(just gernerating text) with pytorch. While i'm referencing some example code on online, got a problem i can't understand.

Here are codes (some codes has been omitted and are not completed yet.):

1. LSTM model (utils.py).

```
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, seq_size, embedding_size, hidden_size):
        super(RNNModule, self).__init__()
        self.seq_size = seq_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, 
                                      embedding_size) 
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size  = embedding_size, 
                            hidden_size = hidden_size,    
                            num_layers = 2,                
                            batch_first=True)
        self.dense = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)
    
        
    def forward(self, x, prev_state):
        embed = self.embedding(x)
        output, state = self.lstm(embed, prev_state)
        logits = self.dense(output)
        print(logits.size())

        return logits, state
    
    # 첫 입력값을 위한 zero state를 출력.
    def zero_state(self, batch_size):
        return (torch.zeros(2, batch_size, self.hidden_size),
                torch.zeros(2, batch_size, self.hidden_size))

def make_data_label(corpus) :
    data = []
    label = []
    for c in corpus :
        data.append(c[:-1])
        label.append(c[1:])

    data, label = torch.LongTensor(data), torch.LongTensor(label)
    return data, label
```

2. main.py

```
if __name__=="__main__":
   
    """ 데이터 불러오기.
    """
    corpus, word2id, id2word, weight = load_data()
    corpus = torch.LongTensor(corpus)
    
    """ 하이퍼 파라미터.
    """
    # 훈련
    epochs = 10
    learning_rate = 0.003
    batch_size = 16   
    hidden_size = 32 # lstm hidden 값 차원수 
    gradients_norm=5 # 기울기 클리핑.

    # 문장 
    seq_size=len(corpus[0])        # 문장 1개 길이.
    embedding_size=len(weight[0]) # 임베딩 벡터 사이즈.
    vocab_size = len(word2id)
    
    # 테스트
    # initial_words=['I', 'am']
    predict_top_k=5
    checkpoint_path='./checkpoint'
        
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    
    print('# corpus size : {} / vocab_size : {}'.format(len(corpus), vocab_size))
    print('# batch size : {}  / num of cell : {}'.format(batch_size, hidden_size))
    print("# 디바이스      : ", device)

    print('-'*30+"데이터 불러오기 및 하이퍼 파라미터 설정 분할 완료.")

    """ data/label 분할
    """
    c = corpus.numpy() # corpus가 Tensor 형태이므로 정상적인 slicing을 위해 numpy 형태로 바꾸어준다.
    data, label = make_data_label(c)
    
    dataset = CommentDataset(data, label)
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

    print('-'*30 + "Data Loader 준비 완료.")
    
    """ Model 정의 및 생성.
    """    
    net = RNNModule(vocab_size, seq_size,
                    embedding_size, hidden_size)
    net = net.to(device)

    loss_f = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    
    for batch_idx, sample in enumerate(dataloader) :
        data, label = sample
        data = data.to(device)
        label = label.to(device)
        
        state_h, state_c = net.zero_state(batch_size) # initial h, c
        state_h = state_h.to(device)
        state_c = state_c.to(device)
        
        logits, (state_h, state_c) = net.forward(data, (state_h, state_c))
        
        print(logits.transpose(1, 2).size())        
        print(label.size())        
        
        loss = loss_f(logits.transpose(1, 2), label)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
        break
```

So, What i can't understand is that why tensor `logits`(code at end of the main.py) must be transposed.

shape of logits and label are:

```
logits : torch.Size([16, 19, 10002]) # [batch_size, setence_length, vocab_size]
label : torch.Size([16, 19])         # [batch_size, setence_length]
```

In my opinion, to calculate loss with CrossEntropy, label's shape and data' shape must be same dimension, but it doesn't. (label's shape : [batch_size, setence_length] -> [batch_size, setence_length, vocab_size])

How can i understand this? and why does it works?

ps. I referenced below website!
: `https://machinetalk.org/2019/02/08/text-generation-with-pytorch/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` does not take in one-hot vectors. Rather, it takes in class values. Therefore, your logits and targets will not be of the same dimensions. Logits have to be of the dimension `(num_examples, vocab_size)` but your label only has to contain the index of the true class so it will have the shape `(num_examples)` not `(num_examples, vocab_size)`. That shape would be needed only if you are feeding in one-hot encoded vectors.

As for why you need to transpose your logits vector, `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` expects the logits vector to be of the dimensions `(batch_size, num_classes,loss_dims)` where loss_dims here would be the number of tokens in each batch.